# Why beeps delay on Atom CPU

Tags: c#, windows-7

I developed a virtual keypad and need to add sound fx. It works an a desktop PC but on an Atom N455 CPU based tablet PC with Windows 7 32 bit, the sound delays when I touch the keypad and it's annoying, you hear the sound when your finger is in the air. I checked, there is no delay with the virtual keypad. Then I noticed all Windows sounds delay. When I adjust the volume level at taskbar I hear the "ding" sound as delayed, say 500+ miliseconds. I also checked there are no CPU/disk consuming processes. I play Angry Birds, all the sound effects are ok, no any annoying delay in that game.

I think that it's not related the code -maybe I have to ask at Superuser intead of Stackoverflow- but below are the codes:

Pre-load the sound into memory

```
 //Load beep into memory
 beep7 = File.ReadAllBytes(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\media\\beep-7.wav");
 mp = new MediaPlayer(beep7); //10 KB wav file
```

Where the sound plays:

```
 mp.Play(); //The sound delays here
```

Comment: sounds like bad touchpad drivers.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Not sure I'd consider that a bad driver when the behavior being discussed is quite normal, and the delay is added by Windows.

Comment: Notice that I use mouse instead of touch, same delay again.

Comment: There is no MediaPlayer constructor that takes a byte[].  Is this actually a SoundPlayer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that the touchpad events are delayed, not the sound itself.

Standard Windows touch processing is waiting to find out whether you're doing a drag, tap, multitouch gesture, etc.  This delay can be eliminated by [using the raw touch interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317326.aspx) instead of the clicks-and-gestures system.  Some touchpads have a feature called "palm rejection" which also adds a delay.

Comment: There is no delay with text display, when I touch the keypad, related  textbox immediately update it's content.

Comment: @NimeCloud: Try calling `RegisterTouchWindow` anyway, it reduced latency significantly for me.  I guess the delay is much easier for the human brain to detect with sounds than visually.

Comment: I'll try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940546(v=vs.85).aspx